# Tabulator persistentFilter not checking for headerFilterEmptyCheck

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Using Tabulator 4.4.3

When filtering the checkbox normally, everything works
If I set a filtered checkbox to true on a column, it works:

```
  headerFilterEmptyCheck: function (value) {
       return !value;
     },
```

However, with using persistentFilter: true and I reload the page, that checkbox filter will only display true=true, never false or null when unchecked (just return 0 rows)

My Column Definition

```
{
     title: "do it?",
     field: "hasToDoIt",
     responsive: 0,
     formatter: "tickCross",
     formatterParams: {
       allowEmpty: true,
       allowTruthy: false,
       tickElement: "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>",
       crossElement: ""
     },
     headerFilter: "tickCross",
     headerFilterEmptyCheck: function (value) {
       return !value; //only filter when the value is true
     },
     sorter: "string",
     headerSortTristate: true,
     width: 80,
     align: 'center'
   },
```

Table Definition

```
new Tabulator("#" + config.Key, {
      index: "_id",
      reactiveData: true,
      persistenceMode: true,
      persistenceID: "accountsummary",
      persistentSort: true,
      persistentFilter: true,
      autoResize: true,
      layout: "fitColumns",
      responsiveLayout: true,
      virtualDomBuffer: 100,
      headerSortTristate: true, //enable tristate header sort for all columns
      data: this.state.Data,
      columns: this.state.Columns,
      groupBy: "Geo",
      groupToggleElement: "header",
      groupStartOpen: true,
      sortOrderReverse: true,
      initialSort: [{ column: "Geo", dir: "asc" }, { column: "Account", dir: "asc" }],
      rowClick: (e, row) => {

        });
      }
```

After selecting the checkbox, reloading the page, the checkbox should show the filtered results and unchecking the box show return to show all rows

Answer (score 0):

This is because persistent filters functionality only persists filters set through the ***setFilter*** function, not header filters.